# Error on setObject with NSMutableDictionary

Tags: objective-c

I'm new in Objective-C, I would like to pupulate a dictionary but i have an error on the line :

```
[fullCollaboraeur setObject:(id)tmpArray forKey:(id)col.Id];
```

This is the full code :

```
NSMutableArray *collaborateurs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
...
NSMutableDictionary *fullCollaboraeur = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
for (Collaborateur *col in  collaborateurs)
 {
  NSMutableArray *tmpArray;
  tmpArray = [fullCollaboraeur objectForKey:(id)col.Id];
  if(tmpArray == nil)
  {
   NSLog(@"Value for %i is null", col.Id);
   tmpArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
   [tmpArray addObject:col];
   [fullCollaboraeur setObject:(id)tmpArray forKey:(id)col.Id];
  }
  else
  {
   NSLog(@"%i", col.Id);
   [tmpArray addObject:col];
   [fullCollaboraeur setObject:tmpArray forKey:(id)col.Id];
  }
 }
```

Can you help me please ?

Many thanks

Comment: are you possibly setting `nil` to a key / value? alloc/init can sometimes fail also. dont forget to release tmparray when you alloc/init it

Comment: wait... what type is col.Id? is it an int?

Comment: Thanks, The error is EXC_BAD_ACCESS. col.Id is int

Comment: If i change col.Id to NSString, it works ... can you say me why ?

Answer (score 5):

NSLog(@"Value for %i is null", col.Id);
    ....
    [fullCollaboraeur setObject:(id)tmpArray forKey:(id)col.Id];

If `Id` is of type (int), it can't be a key in a dictionary directly.  Dictionaries take objects as keys.

Note:

- Type casting is to be avoided.  All those `(id)`s need to go away.  If the compiler is giving a warning on those lines, it is probably indicating a real problem that isn't going to be fixed by type casting.
- instance variables are named with a lowercase letter.  `id` is a reserved word and, thus, should not be used as an instance variable name.  Use something like `columnIdentifier`.

Comment: I wish I could upvote once for the correct answer and another time for the advice against typecasting. Seriously, if your code will not compile without warnings unless you typecast, you're doing something wrong and the compiler is trying to let you know.